# func<string,string,bool> is not a valid windows runtime parameter type (win 8.1)

Tags: c#, windows-8, autocomplete, winrt-xaml

https://github.com/igorkulman/AutoCompleteBox/blob/master/AutoCompleteBox/AutoCompleteBox.cs

I download this control, But I cannot build it,

```
public Func<string, string, bool> SearchFunction
{
   get { return (Func<string, string, bool>)GetValue(SearchFunctionProperty); }
   set { SetValue(SearchFunctionProperty, value); }
}
```

When I try using SearchFunction as public,I am getting this error. When I change it as internal it is working but this time I can't access SearchFunction from my project.

```
Method 'CodeAutoComplete.AutoCompleteBox.SearchFunction.get()' has a parameter of type
 'System.Func<System.String, System.String, System.Boolean>' in its signature. Although 
this generic type is not a valid Windows Runtime type, the type or its generic parameters 
implement interfaces that are valid Windows Runtime types. Consider changing the type 
'System.Func<T1, T2, TResult>' in the method signature. It is not a valid Windows Runtime 
parameter type. C:\\..CodeAutoComplete\AutoCompleteBox.cs CodeAutoComplete (Windows 8.1)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can you supply the definition for the method returned by `GetValue(SearchFunctionProperty)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding the file to a WindowsRuntimeComponent project, add it to Windows store class library (if you have already created the project you can change the output type to class library in project properties->Output type).
The problem is if you create a WindowsRuntime component, you are a [lot more limited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh977010%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#ExportingInvalidTypes) in what  you can make public as everything you make public need to have a valid WindowsRuntime type mapping.